# Transparent material render has super dark shadows in blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm using blender 2.91.2 with cycles render on a mac. I'm trying to export a whiskey bottle and glass. I attached the material settings for the whiskey, as well as the render settings. I increased the number of light bounces, glossy, transparency, and volume in render settings (which a different answer thread suggested to do), **but i am still ending up with the dark area at the top of the cup**. Note that the light source is directly above the cup and bottle, so this shouldn't be an issue. Is there another setting to adjust?

[image: render][image: whiskey material settings][image: render settings]

[image: after Clear Custom Split Normals Data]

Comment: Can you share the file to have a closer look?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14wu0MMmXIBPQ1-LsF3dTv7OQLkwap9zZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't see this black spot, are your sure it's not the refraction that makes us see the bottle?

Comment: I can't see this black spot, are your sure it's not the refraction that makes us see the bottle? Also maybe recalculate the normals, and in the Object Data > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data

Comment: The black spot is at the top of the liquid in the cup. I will try your suggestion after work

Comment: I implemented your suggestion, but now the top of the whiskey is transparent — any other workaround for this? I attached a screenshot in the original post.

Comment: I can't see any problem as soon as I recalculate the normals of the water. Maybe it's because of overlapping faces and try to scale a bit?

Comment: I tried both and neither worked. Are you using cycles render? Is it possible for you to send me your version of the file?

Comment: @Sam, I've used what you sent me, and didn't get the problem with Cycles, what version of Blender are you using? I hope someone will understand

Comment: I'm using 2.91.2. I can try upgrading tomorrow.

Comment: I upgraded, opened the file, and still have the same result. So not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Hopefully someone else can find a solution. at this point the project is stuck at this stage.